# Diffeence between てばかり(は/も)いられない and てはいられない

Tags: grammar, nuances, use-and-frequency

I would like to know the difference and usage (frequency, oral/written) for てばかりはいられない with regards to てはいられない

Both seem to be pretty close:

> 人生そんなに長くないのだから待っ**てばかりはいられない**。 Life is short so I can’t wait forever.
>
> どんなに辛くても、泣い**てばかりもいられない**。 No matter how tough it is, I can’t keep crying.
>
> 明日は早く起きるので、いつものように遅くまでテレビを見**てはいられない**。I have to wake up early tomorrow, so I can’t watch TV until late as usual.

Comment: You're asking some good questions, but this site doesn't have many people who are able to answer them. This is your fifth question in less than 24 hours. Can I respectfully suggest that you slow down your question rate a little. Particularly at weekends, the rate of answering is slow (perhaps people are enjoying a well earned break). Your questions are likely to slip down the list and be missed before they get answered. Fewer questions at a time will also reduce the burden on those that do the answering. Thanks.

Comment: Oh thank you for your remark.  I will take it into account. Sorry, I did not mean to put some kind of pressure. And thanks for explaining how the site works.

Comment: And I am grateful for all the help I already received.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think it may make things clearer to look at `てばかりいられない` as a combination of two separate grammar points: `てばかりいる` and `ていられない`.

`ていられない`, as you seem to know, expresses the inability to continuously be in some state, or to continue being in that state. I couldn't find a good site for this in English, but here is a pretty simple [explanation in Japanese](https://nihongokyoshi-net.com/2020/01/16/jlptn2-grammar-tewairarenai/). A simple example might be:

> もうこれ以上待っていられない
>
> I can't wait any more than this

`てばかりいる` is used to describe doing nothing but a certain thing, typically with critical or negative connotations. Here's a [simple explanation](https://learnjapanesedaily.com/japanese-grammar-%E3%81%B0%E3%81%8B%E3%82%8A%E3%81%84%E3%82%8B-bakariiru.html). A simple example might be:

> スマホを見てばかりいると目が悪くなりますよ
>
> If you're always looking at your smartphone, your eyesight will get worse

Consequently, `てばかりいられない` expresses the inability to (continuously) do just one thing. So translations for your examples might look something like this:

> 人生そんなに長くないのだから待ってばかりはいられない
>
> Life is short, so I can't **just** keep waiting forever
>
> どんなに辛くても、泣いてばかりもいられない
>
> No matter how hard it gets, I can't **just** keep crying

In both cases, `ばかりいられない` is expressing the fact that the speaker can't keep doing nothing but these specific actions at the expense of other things. Just `待っていられない` or `泣いていられない` would suggest that the speaker simply couldn't wait or couldn't cry for any significant period of time, whereas the actual implication is that the speaker can't continue to do *nothing but crying or waiting*. Again I couldn't find a great explanation in English, but [here's one in Japanese](http://www.edewakaru.com/archives/18833436.html).

Comment: Great explanation, and thank youbfor the links